# Ext JS 3.4 : Event listener for cell editing

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm facing issue of firing edit event using cell editor in `Ext Js 3.4`.

I'm trying to achieve triggering an ajax call upon a cell edited after pressing `'Enter'`.

For now, I just replaced with `console.log('hi')` but it doesn't show anything after I pressed `'Enter'`.

I'm not sure what's wrong in my code. Appreciate if someone can point it out. Thanks.

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: api_store,
    loadMask: true,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Create',
        handler: function () { }
    }],
    columns: [
        {
            id: 'name',
            header: 'Key Name',
            width: 300,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'name',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false,
                listener: {
                    edit: function (el) {
                        console.log('hi');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            header: 'Key Value',
            width: 500,
            sortable: false,
            dataIndex: 'key'
        }
    ],
    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({ singleSelect: true }),
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    height: 210,
    stripeRows: true,
    height: 350,
    title: 'Keys'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Use EditorGridPanel `afteredit` event:

> afteredit(e)
>
> Fires after a cell is edited. The edit event object has the following
>   properties
>
> - grid - This grid
> - record - The record being edited
> - field - The field name being edited
> - value - The value being set
> - originalValue - The original value for the field, before the edit.
> - row - The grid row index
> - column - The grid column index
>
> Parameters:
>
> e : Object An edit event (see above for description)

**Example:**

```
Ext.onReady(function () {        

        var api_store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: ['key', 'name'],
            data: [
                ['1', 'Name1'],
                ['2', 'Name2'],
                ['3', 'Name3']
            ]
        });


        var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store: api_store,
            loadMask: true,
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            tbar: [{
                text: 'Create',
                handler: function () { }
            }],
            listeners: {
                afteredit: function(e) {
                    console.log('After edit. Column: ' + e.field);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    id: 'name',
                    header: 'Key Name',
                    width: 300,
                    sortable: true,
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Key Value',
                    width: 500,
                    sortable: false,
                    dataIndex: 'key'
                }
            ],
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({ singleSelect: true }),
            viewConfig: {
                forceFit: true
            },
            height: 210,
            stripeRows: true,
            height: 350,
            title: 'Keys'
        });     

});
```